# What is a word that describes a monolithic national identity?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, etymology, nouns

Something similar in French would be la jacobinisme (Jacobinism); however, I’m not looking for a political party but a phrase or word in the English lexicon.

The definition would be:
[Blank] is a noun that describes a centralized nation state coupled with a monolithic national identity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***[Chauvinism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism):***

> a form of extreme patriotism and nationalism, a fervent faith in
> national excellence and glory. It is an irrational belief in the
> superiority or dominance of one's own group or people, who are seen as
> strong and virtuous, while others are considered weak or unworthy.

A less strong but still apt term  is ***[Nationalism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism)***

> is an idea and movement that promotes the interests of a particular nation (as in a group of people) especially with the aim of gaining and maintaining the nation's sovereignty (self-governance) over its homeland.

(Wikipedia)